# Run a button in an Excel-Add-In (Jedox) using VBA

Tags: excel, vba, business-intelligence, jedox

I have the following simple Excel spreadsheet:

```
      A             B       
1    Revenue       5.000    =PALO.DATAC("Jedox Server";"P&L";"Revenue")
2    Costs        -3.000    =PALO.DATAC("Jedox Server";"P&L";"COSTS")
3    Profit        2.000    =SUM(B1:B2)
4
5
```

As you can see in cell `B1` and `B2` I am ussing the BI-Tool https://www.jedox.com/en/ in order to insert the `Revenue` and the `Costs` from an `OLAP-Cube`.

All this works perfectly so far.

---

With the Excel-Add-In of the BI-Tool I can also create a so-called `OLAP Screenshot`:

[image]

When I cklick on this button a new file is created in which the formulas in **Cell B1** and **B2** are deleted and only the values are displayed (in this case: `5.000` and `-3.000`).

Now, I want that I can trigger this button with a VBA code. Something like this:

```
Sub OLAP_Screenshot()
Go to Excel-Addin "Jedox"
Click on "Speichern als Snapshot"
End Sub
```

Do you have any idea how the VBA code must look like to activate this button in the BI-Tool?

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution would be to map the shortcut:

```
SendKeys ("%Y1D"), True
```

Where 
%= alt, activates keyboard shortcuts
Y1= ribbon shortcut (change to what the Jedox  plugin is mapped as) 
D = button shortcut (change to what the Speichern als Snapshot button is mapped as)

> WARNING: You should only use the SendKeys Method if no other option is
>   available, because it can cause problems, if the wrong window is
>   active when the code runs.

Alternatively look in the VBA object library and add: tools>references>Jedox

From here it would look something like: (I do not have the plugin installed)

```
Sub SAS

Dim Jedox As JedoxExcelAddIn
Set Jedox= Application.COMAddIns.Item("Jedox.ExcelAddIn").Object
Jedox.'Speichern als Snapshot'

End Sub
```